# Автоматическая установка приложения PYTHON+AUTOIT

Tags: python, pycharm, autoit

Всем здравствуйте! Мне необходимо написать скрипт , который автоматически устанавливает ПО на ПК.
Я пытаюсь написать это на python.
Вот мой код:

```
import autoit
autoit.run('C:\\Users\\Public\\Наименование программы.exe')
```

pycharm мне выдаёт ошибку :

```
  File "D:/AUTOIT_XPOS/main.py", line 4, in <module>
    autoit.run('FrontolxPOS.exe')
  File "D:\AUTOIT_XPOS\venv_v\lib\site-packages\autoit\autoit.py", line 80, in wrapper
    raise AutoItError(err_msg)
autoit.autoit.AutoItError: run program failed
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, что я делаю не так?

Comment: Установка программы точно не требует прав администратора? Если программу установки запускать напрямую, без Автоита - никаких окошек ОС не появляется типа "подтвердите действие" и т. п.? Возможно, проблема в этом

Comment: нет, установка не требует прав.

Comment: Установила виртуалку win7, на ней запускается скрипт autoit, на win10 не запускается.. Ошибок нет, но установщик не открывается. Есть идеи почему так может быть? uac отключен и там, и там

Comment: Решилось так: Нужно было просто Pycharm отрыть от Админа...